# Automatically Generating java code for xml layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, class, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have got an idea to get rid of some coding when we do `initializion of views`.
When we create an `xml layout` in android. At that movement same name `class` is created with `UpperCase Letters` with a dialogue with permission. And as i created views with ids. It should create Views and initialize them automatically.

**for e.g**

close.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/close_img" />

 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/closeText"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Testing Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And automatically generated java code should be.

```
public class Close extends Activity
{

  TextView CloseText;

  Button CloseBtn;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CloseText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.closeText);

        CloseBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);
     }
}
```

I can read xml and do the other stuff as I explained. But how could i add this module to eclipse and How could i create a service which work in Background all the time in eclipse.

**Suggest me** how to add this module(Plugin) to eclipse and i am going to use `JAXB to generate Java Objects from XML document`. Is there any better option.

Comment: 1.off-topic as *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*  2. already answered(i'm pretty sure that I saw similar question in last week) ... 3. there is plenty annotation based library for this

Comment: So why don't you share one @Selvin. It means if you have no answer then downVote it. And where i have asked to recommend a book,software etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a
This can help you !

Answer (score 2):

Here in this website i find that just paste the xml and you will get your java code ready for activity class.
[i had attached the link](https://www.buzzingandroid.com/tools/android-layout-finder/)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.